# about Simple PHP MVC example

Tags: php, model-view-controller

[In there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022231/simple-php-mvc-example)
 exist a simple example of MVC in PHP. the problem is, this example just work when this

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
if(function_exists($action) && !substr($action,0,1)=="_"){
    $action();
}else{
    echo "<h1>404 Page Not Found</h1><p>The page you requested could not be found</p>";
}
```

changed to:

```
    $action = $_GET['action'];
if(function_exists($action) || !substr($action,0,1)=="_"){
    $action();
}else{
    echo "<h1>404 Page Not Found</h1><p>The page you requested could not be found</p>";
}
```

**&&** changed to **||**. or completely **!substr($action,0,1)=="_"** removed. What does this line is not allowed to run **$action**?

=======================

Edit: Problem is that router don't work with **&&**!

Comment: Why do you want it like that? The _ typically is to keep track of private functions which should only be used from within other class functions.

Comment: Why is this tagged with "mvc"? The question should be "How does substr() work?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with change

From:

```
if(function_exists($action) && !substr($action,0,1)=="_")
```

To:

```
if(function_exists($action) && !(substr($action,0,1)=="_"))
```

Answer (score 1):

its because `&&` is `and`

so this way

```
if(function_exists($action) && !substr($action,0,1)=="_"){
```

If the function exsits `AND` the `substr` not contains _ than run

this means

`||` is `or` so this means

```
if(function_exists($action) || !substr($action,0,1)=="_"){
```

if the function exsits but the string contains `_` it will fail,
or if the function does not exsists, but the string doesnt contain an `_` it will still fail.

So `&&` check if both are okay, what `||` no matter if one of them is valid or true, if the other fails or not valid, it will give you the 404 as you specified above

I hope it helped you, and if it wasnt clear i will try to describe it in a nother way

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. i have no problem with syntax, my talk is just when **&&** changed to **||** the router works. ok?